# CSS - Background color oversizing / covering paragraph text rather than just h3

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a background color for a h3 which is at the bottom of a paragraph however the color is covering both the heading and the paragraph text when I just want it to cover the h3. Not sure why its oversizing like that rather than just wrapping around the h3.

This is how I've done it -

```css
section.council {
  height: 350px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

.council h2 {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  line-height: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000;
}

.council p {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.readmore h3 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00BFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h4>LATEST CASE STUDY</h4>
  <div class="six columns">
    <h2>Wakefield Council</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel ex nisl. Vestibulum vitae ultricies nisl. Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci.
      <br> Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor. Suspendisse nec venenatis nisi. Phasellus sodales viverra ante quis efficitur. Pellentesque quis orci mi.
    </p>
    <div class="readmore">
      <h3>READ MORE</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't see what's going wrong exactly? To me, it only colors the background of the <h3> element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your problem just the fact that `h3` as a block element by default goes over the whole width …?

Well then just make it inline or inline-block, and move text-align to the parent element to center it:

```css
section.council {
  height: 350px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

.council h2 {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  line-height: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000;
}

.council p {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.readmore {
   text-align:center;
}
.readmore h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #00BFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h4>LATEST CASE STUDY</h4>
  <div class="six columns">
    <h2>Wakefield Council</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel ex nisl. Vestibulum vitae ultricies nisl. Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci.
      <br> Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor. Suspendisse nec venenatis nisi. Phasellus sodales viverra ante quis efficitur. Pellentesque quis orci mi.
    </p>
    <div class="readmore">
      <h3>READ MORE</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

If you want it to look more button-y, then add a bit of padding as well.

Comment: Thanks, man. Had a complete brain freeze. How do I make the background stretch out a bit further either side of the heading? I want it to cover the length of the text above (it's for someone else).

Comment: What text above, the text content of the paragraph? That is not that easy; first of all, there is no direct relation between that paragraph text and the headline, and secondly the paragraph is still wider than the text inside it, so you can not easily measure where the text itself breaks.

Comment: If I use a load of padding & margin it'll work though, right?

Comment: Depends ... I mean, what exactly do you want to align it to - where the last line of the paragraph ends? That is going to change, based on the available screen width. Plus, it could be _very_ short, if just one single word gets forced onto the next line. Or something else ...?